# Selenium long checking that element is present on DOM

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to detect whether any elements are visible inside the basket after opening the page.

If an element is present I'm voiding it immediately to clear the basket for the test to have "clear data".

Code:

This is DOM code:

```
<div class="product-box">
    <div>
        <div class="rc-swipeout">
            <div class="rc-swipeout-cover"></div>
            <div class="rc-swipeout-actions rc-swipeout-actions-right">
                <div class="rc-swipeout-btn swipeout-minus" role="button">
                    <div class="rc-swipeout-btn-text"><span class="material-icons minus-icon " style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 24px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">remove</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rc-swipeout-btn swipeout-plus" role="button">
                    <div class="rc-swipeout-btn-text"><span class="material-icons plus-icon " style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 24px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">add</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rc-swipeout-btn swipeout-remove" role="button">
                    <div class="rc-swipeout-btn-text"><span class="material-icons delete-icon " style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 24px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">delete</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rc-swipeout-content" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
                <div class="cart-item-container" data-product-key="c754870c-fd8a-96a3-04f3-8300f11b3b22">
                    <div class="cart-item-container-content">
                        <div class="cart-item-name-container">
                            <div class="cart-item-hideoverflow">
                                <!-- react-text: 1969 -->Latte
                                <!-- /react-text --><span class="cart-item-size">(Normal)</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item-count-container">
                            <div>1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item-price">
                            <div>
                                <div>3.50</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rc-swipeout">
            <div class="rc-swipeout-cover"></div>
            <div class="rc-swipeout-actions rc-swipeout-actions-right">
                <div class="rc-swipeout-btn swipeout-minus" role="button">
                    <div class="rc-swipeout-btn-text"><span class="material-icons minus-icon " style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 24px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">remove</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rc-swipeout-btn swipeout-plus" role="button">
                    <div class="rc-swipeout-btn-text"><span class="material-icons plus-icon " style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 24px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">add</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="rc-swipeout-btn swipeout-remove" role="button">
                    <div class="rc-swipeout-btn-text"><span class="material-icons delete-icon " style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 24px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">delete</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rc-swipeout-content" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
                <div class="cart-item-container product-active" data-product-key="187cf8f5-0b0b-810f-919d-479995b356a0">
                    <div class="cart-item-container-content">
                        <div class="cart-item-name-container">
                            <div class="cart-item-hideoverflow">
                                <!-- react-text: 1994 -->Hot Dog
                                <!-- /react-text --><span class="cart-item-size">(Normal)</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item-count-container">
                            <div>1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item-price">
                            <div>
                                <div>3.50</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1) Elements:

```
private static readonly By BasketRowsLocator = By.XPath("//div[@class = 'cart-item-container-content']");
```

```
public IList<IWebElement> BasketRowsElements => driver.FindElements(BasketRowsLocator);
```

2) Method

```
public bool IsBasketNotEmpty()
{
    if (BasketRowsElements.Count > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

3) Final method in NUnit setup

```
private void ValidateEmptyBasket()
{
    try
    {
        var basketResult = mainPosPage.BasketComponent.IsBasketNotEmpty();
        if (basketResult == true)
        {
            mainPosPage.LeftActionBarComponent.VoidElement.Click();
            mainPosPage.WorkSpaceComponent.VoidDialogBoxComponent.YesButtonElement.Click();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

When something is inside the basket deletion is done ultra fast, but when basket is empty it waits couple of seconds and after that it's moving to perform the test.

I've tried also setting the method inside TeadDown, but the wait is the same... any ideas?

Comment: Have you got any implicit waits set on your driver object?  The side effect of using implicit waits is that if you set a 2 second implicit wait, any check to see if something does not exist will take 2 seconds.

Comment: well actually it is set to big number, that might be a problem. However I need that least to be 5 sec. Can I somehow overwrite that implicit wait in the method I've shown?

Comment: You can set the implicit wait to 0 before the find element call and then set it back to the default after the find element call.  Generally I would suggest removing the implicit waits completely and adding in Explicit waits where required.  Implicit waits are an anti-pattern and cause all sorts of unexpected side effects